# Show a dialog when the actionbar 'up' button is pressed, and prevent activity from finishing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            backPressed();
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

`backPressed()` creates a dialog, and should wait for button click. If 'ok' is pressed, finish the activity, else, don't finish the activity.

At the moment the dialog is created, but then the activity finishes and the dialog disappears.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: This is not a good idea. First, it is user-hostile. Second, the user has many other ways of leaving your activity (BACK, HOME, recent-task list, accepting an incoming phone call, notification drawer entry, etc.), so you need to be able to handle the user leaving at any point anyway.

Comment: Although I agree with @CommonsWare looks like what you're missing is `return true;` instead of `break;`.

Comment: @matiash that worked, thank you. Create an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you return **true** from `onOptionsItemSelected()`, you're basically telling Android *"I didn't handle this, do whatever you are supposed to do with it"*.

In this case, since you want to intercept the `home` action, just return true after calling `backPressed()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        backPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```